How to make FontDescription(pango) with FontFace from cairo in Rust?
I have a font binary in font.rs and load it with freetype-rs, with cairo-rs + freetype feature i can convert Face from freetype-rs into cairo FontFace.
But i did not find a way to make pango FontDescription with these things.
Cairo show_text with FontFace:
mod font;
use std::{fs::File, rc::Rc};

use cairo::freetype as ft;
use pangocairo::cairo::{self, Context, FontFace, Format, ImageSurface};

fn main() {
    let lib = ft::Library::init().unwrap();
    let fontface = lib
        .new_memory_face(Rc::new(font::RAW_FONT.to_vec()), 0)
        .unwrap();
    let cairo_face = FontFace::create_from_ft(&fontface).unwrap();

    // Create Cairo surface and context
    let width = 800;
    let height = 600;
    let surface = ImageSurface::create(Format::ARgb32, width, height).unwrap();
    let cr = Context::new(&surface).unwrap();

    // Create Cairo font face from FreeType face
    cr.rectangle(0., 0., 800., 600.);
    cr.set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    cr.fill().unwrap();

    // Render text
    cr.set_font_face(&cairo_face);
    cr.move_to(100.0, 100.0);
    cr.set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cr.set_font_size(20.);
    cr.show_text("90.89%").unwrap();

    // Save the image to a PNG file
    let mut st = File::create("output.png").unwrap();
    surface.write_to_png(&mut st).unwrap();
}

here's font.rs if you need it.
